# How to shim a doorknob latch plate

Tags: doors, doorknob, latches

I'm replacing all the doorknobs in my new house. The new knobs "latch plates" (not sure what the proper term is) are thinner than the old ones, so they sit a bit too deep in the space that was cut out of the door (see image below). Is there any easy way to shim the plate? This is purely for cosmetic reasons (it functions fine as is). Pre-made hardware would be ideal, and maybe I'm just lacking the right search term.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shim is not visible, so you could make your own shim out of cardboard -- more than one layer, if needed.

Comment: As a mention, the cardboard does not need to be cut precisely. One piece for the top and bottom about 7/8" wide by 3/8" tall +/-. Sometimes its a trick to keep them in place while you are trying to get the latch back in place, but it will work, and if you get it the right thickness the first time, you only need to do it once.. It looks like 2 thicknesses are needed, Cut 2 pieces approx. 3/4X3/4" and score both squares partway through middle and fold on the score, then insert. The screws will readily go through the cardboard. My apologies Phil, just needed a little more detail.

Answer (score 1):

If the latching mechanism is adjustable, then just a few washers behind  that plate will bring it out. Your home store will also have shim sets.

If the latching mechanism isn't adjustable and can't be moved out, then you have to find a round hole strike plate that will fit over your "latch plate" to fill in the space. You'll need something like the one below but you'll have to check dimensions.

[image]